# How to ensure that an Activity is only opened one time after pressed multiple time on button

Tags: android, buttonclick

I have a button that opens an activity. But I noticed that when I press multiple times on the button before the activity appears it opens the activity twice. (I'm using android:onclick in my XML) So I put this code :

```
AppCompatImageButton natureButton;

public void onClickButton(View view){
 natureButton = findViewById(view.getId());
        natureButton.setEnabled(false);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //Enabled the button after activity is no longer visible to the user
        natureButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

I called onStop() to enabled the button because onStop() is called when the activity is no longer visible.
So I want to know if there is a better approach to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding in:

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of enabling the button in `onStop`, the better approach will be to enable it in `onResume`.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(natureButton != null)
       natureButton.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Sure, but I'm using android:onClick and my AppCompatImageButton is initialized in my onClickButton (View view). But when the activity is launched the onResume() is called before the view is initialized.

Comment: You can check whether the button is null or not. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't think about that. But the answer of "a_local_nobody" seems to be the better approach.